# Can $\omega_1$ be supercompact?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals, forcing

Is "ZF + $\omega_1$ is supercompact" consistent relative to "ZFC + there is a supercompact cardinal"?

In particular, if $\delta$ is supercompact, does it remain so in $V(\mathbb{R} \cap V[G])$ where $G \subset Col(\omega,<\delta)$ is $V$-generic?  This seems to be the case for measurability but I am having trouble proving it for supercompactness.  It seems likely that someone else has tried this, so I though I'd ask here.

The appropriate definition of supercompactness in ZF is the one in terms of normal fine measures, where normality is defined using diagonal intersections.

I am aware that $\omega_1$ has some amount of supercompactness under AD. I am interested in a more direct proof using forcing, which I hope will give (full) supercompactness.

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/87430/what-sort-of-large-cardinal-can-aleph-1-be-without-the-axiom-of-choice


Comment: Ah, I thought I remembered a question like that on here but I couldn't find it.  Sorry for posting a similar question.

Comment: Trevor, I think that my question may be a bit overly broad. It is just like the time I asked about the ability to destroy weak choice principles (or add some of them) via generic extensions (unlike full choice), and later Stefan Geschke asked about a concrete example. It's a reasonable question when trying to tackle a broad question, I think.

Comment: The Jech construction preserves supercompactness. This is Lemma 1.3 in Apter-Henle, Large cardinal structures below $\aleph_{\omega}$.

Comment: @TanmayInamdar: Great! Could you post that as an answer? (Maybe including the statement of the relevant theorem?)

Comment: Umm, I'd feel a bit embarrassed to do so given that I haven't read the paper myself. Arthur Apter mentioned it to my supervisor Benedikt Loewe in some correspondence that they had about this, citing this particular lemma. So I think asking Arthur Apter about this would be a better way to know the exact reference. On the other hand, I'm actually currently writing up what I think is a proof of the same thing, but it'll take a few days to complete. If you would like, I could send you a copy of that once I'm done with it.

Comment: @TanmayInamdar: I would definitely be interested in your write-up when it's done.  My website is in my profile page now and contains my e-mail address.

Answer (score 3):

While might not be a full and satisfactory answer, you might be interested in the following paper by Spector:

> Spector, M. **[Iterated extended ultrapowers and supercompactness without choice.](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1134195)**,
>   *Ann. Pure Appl. Logic* **54** (1991), no. 2, 179–194.

Comment: Thanks, that mentions a way to extend an ultrapower of Ord taken under ZF to an ultrapower of $V$ in a class generic extension.  This would be a useful thing to do if $\omega_1$ were supercompact.  It looks like the only example given of supercompactness without choice given in the article comes from AD though.

Comment: Trevor, I had several chats over a cup of coffee with Magidor on the problem of an inner model for supercompactness. If you think about Solovay's model it has an $L(\mathbb R)$ sort of construction, and in a sense if we make $\aleph_1$ measurable we essentially take some inner model of measurability. However supercompactness does not yet have such canonical inner model, so I don't think that it's that easy to construct a model of $\aleph_1$ being supercompact for all $\lambda$.

Comment: If you have an idea how to uniformly preserve the supercompact measures on a proper class of cardinals, maybe I can help with the symmetries themselves later on. However if the idea works it seems reasonable that it may solve (or at least advance) the work towards a canonical inner model for supercompactness.

Comment: I was hoping that the inner model would just be $V(\mathbb{R} \cap V[G])$.  Doesn't this work for measurability?  Every subset of $\delta$ in this model is added by some proper initial segment of $G$.  So we have a measure on $\delta$ given by the union of the small-forcing extensions of the original measure.  This is countably complete, again because every countable sequence is added by a proper initial segment of the forcing.  But if there is a countably complete measure on $\delta$ then there is a normal measure.

Comment: ...This argument fails to adapt to supercompactness in two ways: first, the set being measured is not added by any proper initial segment of the forcing, and second, normality does not come for free with $\mathcal{P}_\kappa(\lambda)$.  Could you explain how the question relates to the inner model problem for supercompact cardinals?

Comment: Well, I can't really explain why I find this related to the inner model problem. This is just a gut feeling that I have. While I know the basics on large cardinals, and I know a bit more than the basics on symmetric extensions I have to admit that I'm not sure how I feel about the combination of the two (I recently began toying with "large $\aleph_1$ models"). However the issue with the inner model problem is exactly the fact that the normal SC measures are not "uniform" enough to relativize down as nice as measurability in the $L[\mu]$ case.

Comment: ...This is a similar case to the symmetries problem. There is no nice symmetric class name of normal measures everywhere. Methinks that if this were to be solved then a class-forcing sort of arguments would have to be used, something like coding "enough" measures and *then* collapsing to $\aleph_1$. This is merely a shot from the hip, and I haven't got the slightest clue *how* to do it, or whether or not it would work.

Comment: I see.  My question might succeed in avoiding that difficult issue because it's okay with me if the model where $\omega_1$ is supercompact contains $V$ (it might therefore be non-canonical.)  One does have to go to an inner model at some point just because forcing preserves AC, which contradicts the thing I'm trying to force, but it doesn't have to be a canonical inner model.

Comment: Oops, I did not see your last comment before posting.  I would be satisfied to get any fixed amount of supercompactness of $\omega_1$.  Does this make it easier?

Comment: Let me find some more references... :-)

Comment: Hmm. I was sure that I saw something like this, but apparently I was thinking on Spector's proposed inner model (which I was informed is not good, so I would probably look for more information about those). All I could find was papers about the amount of supercompactness of $\aleph_1$ and $\aleph_2$ in models of AD; which I believe is not what you are looking for. I have some vague idea, but I don't know enough large cardinals theory to work the details... I'll try to read about it some more and see if I can make something out of it.